# I don't see the "delete app" button on my iPhone, how do I do?

Tags: iphone, ios

Per a [post](https://www.rd.com/article/how-to-delete-apps-iphone/), there would be "delete app" button in General | iPhone Storage ...

[image]

However, my iPhone shows as follows

[image]

per [apple support](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/remove-apps-iph248b543ca/ios), I could "Touch and hold the app in App Library, tap Delete App"

however, my iPhone shows as follows

[image]

How do I delete the app actually from my iPhone?

Comment: Have you downloaded the app via the App Store or via Safari ("Add shortcut to Home Screen")?

Comment: @Thinkr via App Store with my AppleID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you're allowed to delete apps in *Settings > Screen Time > Content & Privacy Restrictions > iTunes & App Store Purchases > Deleting Apps*. If you're not, click "**Allow**".

[image]

This is likely to solve your problem, the default behavior of this section of Screen Time is quite annoying but once you found it, it should work.